# Problem trying to access local website (settings in hosts file) on Host PC (Win XP SP3) from Guest PC (VM Win 7)

Tags: iis, windows-7, windows-xp, ip-address, hosts-file

***Host PC :***

```
Windows XP SP3
```

***Guest PC :***

```
Virtual Machine running Windows 7 SP1
```

***Host PC IP Address :***

```
172.16.5.55
```

***Guest PC IP Address :***

```
172.16.6.62
```

On my Guest PC I'm trying to access a website running on my Host PC.  My Host PC's hosts file has the entry of:

```
172.16.5.55     www.dev.com
```

When I modify my Guest PC's hosts file to:

```
172.16.6.62     www.dev.com
```

and open up Internet Explorer 9 and type in http://www.dev.com, it says Page not found. Any ideas on what I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It doesn't matter that the IP's are different.  I just needed to use the same hosts file settings as my host.  I don't know why I hadn't tried that already, but simply changing

```
172.16.6.62    www.dev.com
```

back to

```
172.16.5.55    www.dev.com
```

did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

What are the subnet masks for both host and guest systems? It looks like they both should be 255.255.0.0 based on the IPs that you have identified.

Comment: Even though they are both tied to the same physical NIC, the physical on the host and the virtual on the guest are treated as separate NICs which do not know of the existence of the other. Since the web server is on the host, they both need to refer to the host's IP.

Comment: It's probably just getting your head around "virtual" mimicking "physical" with the hypervisors.